# Make the UI Display before completing the function Execution.Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Function Which will send the emails to different recievers say Actor1, actor2 etc. Before sending the auto generated email the user should be able to edit it. 
I have used a placeholder to display the autogenered email content and a textbox to add the new content. 
My function looks like this

```
public void SendEmail(var content)
{
...
display1= actor1content;
....
....
dsplay2=actor2content;
}
```

Here display1 and display2 are the controls which i am putting to placeholder. Now after function execution two displays will come together. How can I make the function to make display1 to appear first and then continue function execution and again make display2 appear.

Comment: Confused - if its *auto generated* then it "should" be (auto/lookup/etc). If you want to edit the content, then simply provide a form to your user and fill in the not-auto-content and then send(?)

Comment: I am able to do that now .. But There are different format of mails which need to send to different type of users... So if there are ten type of users are there i will get ten pop ups at a time. Instead I want the popus to appear one by one .. i.e once for actor one the mail content is generated i want to display it .. And again continue function execution and display second..

Answer (score 1):

You could use an UpdatePanel to prevent a full PostBack , and a Timer to trigger an async PostBack every 5 seconds or so. When the async PostBack occurs, you could check the status of your background operation and if you need user input (eg: if the operation has completed), register a startup script to display an alert/prompt.